# Paid developer account required to enable cloudkit under capabilities for xcode 8?

Tags: xcode8, cloudkit

In Xcode 8 Under capabilities, it shows 9 capabilities are unavailable including cloudkit. Do i have to pay 99$ to enrol as a paid developer so that i can use cloudkit?? I jus want to use it for learning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will require paid developer account for CloudKit.

Initially, they do give free storage for testing or development purpose but when it grows more you will require to Pay.

[Reference Supported capabilities (iOS)](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6)

Comment: @Rajneesh071 For now Apple don't provide any such option to learn. You will need to enroll for Apple Developer Program for certain capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

To enable the feature you do need a paid account

**Source:**

> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html

For storage once you have a paid licence, apple offer a generous quota:

**Source:**

> https://developer.apple.com/icloud/